# Mostrar señal digital (cuadrada) en gráfica

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

Tengo un vector de ceros y unos, después le aumenté ruido para simular una señal y a continuación la filtré.

El problema es que al graficar me salen graficas con picos y no cuadradas, entonces mi pregunta es ¿cómo cambiar la escala para que parezcan cuadráticas o aumentar en otro vector los mismos números repetidos?, por ejemplo: `v=[1,0,1,0]` y el vector final sea `v'=[1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0]`.

Me valdría cualquier otro idea para que parezca más una señal cuadrada. Adjunto el código:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def clear():
    print ("\n" * 50)

plt.clf()
clear() 
pure=np.array([1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1 ])
noise = np.random.normal(0.2, 0.4, pure.shape)
signal = pure + noise
final=[]
t=0.5
for x in range (len(pure)):
    if (signal[x] > t):
        final.append(1)
    else :
        final.append(0)
print(pure)
print(signal)
print(final)

plt.subplot(1,1,1)
plt.title('Señal final')
plt.ylabel('Voltaje (V)')
plt.xlabel('Tempo (s)')
p=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
plt.plot(p,final)
plt.show()

plt.title('Señal inicial')
plt.ylabel('Voltaje (V)')
plt.xlabel('Tempo (s)')
p=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
plt.plot(p,pure)
plt.show()

plt.subplot(1,1,1)
plt.title('Señal con ruidol')
plt.ylabel('Voltaje (V)')
plt.xlabel('Tempo (s)')
p=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
plt.plot(p,signal)
plt.show()
```

adjunto gráfica, hay otras 2 pero no las publiqué:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que buscas es el parámetro [`drawstyle`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_drawstyle) de `matplotlib.pyplot.plot`:

- `steps-pre`: el paso entre los dos valores extremos se establece al comienzo del segmento, es decir, la línea estará a la derecha del valor `y` del punto .

  ```
  plt.plot(p, final, drawstyle='steps-pre')
  ```

  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- `steps-post`: el paso se establece al final del segmento, es decir, la línea estará a la izquierda del valor `y` del punto .

  ```
  plt.plot(p, final, drawstyle='steps-post')
  ```

  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- `steps-mid`: el paso se establece en medio de dos puntos.

  ```
  plt.plot(p, final, drawstyle='steps-mid')
  ```

  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias, al final use el `plt.plot(p,final,drawstyle='steps-mid')` en todas las lineas necesarias, pase 2 días en ese problema, muchas gracias!