# como generar un gráfico cuadrado en higchart

Tags: php, highcharts, charts

Quisiera alguna orientación de como generar gráficos cuadrados en hihchart, he encontrado un pregunta similar pero está relacionada a Python y mi desarrollo en en php laravel 8: [https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/345026/mostrar-se%c3%b1al-digital-cuadrada-en-gr%c3%a1fica](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/345026/mostrar-se%C3%B1al-digital-cuadrada-en-gr%C3%A1fica)

los datos que se recepcionan son binarios (0 o 1) en intervalos irregulares, la idea es que si s recepciona un valor 1, el gráfico se mantenga en ese valor hasta cambiar de estado generando el gráfico cuadrado.

Comment: Hola, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: y que has intentado???